# Javascript doesn't throw error while trying to call get on an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, getter-setter

I'm trying to implement a service using AngularJS to manage cookies.

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .service('CookiesService', ['$cookies', function ($cookies) {

        var cookies = {
            cookie1: {},
            cookie2: {}
        };

        function CookiesService() {
        }

        CookiesService.prototype.update= function(name, options) {
            cookies[name] = options ? options : {};
        };


        CookiesService.prototype.isCookie = function(name) {
            if(!cookies.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                throw 'Unknown cookie name';
            }
            return cookies.hasOwnProperty(name);
        };

        function getter(prototype, name, getter) {
            Object.defineProperty(prototype, name, {
                get:getter, 
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true,
            });
         }

         Object.keys(cookies).forEach(function(name) {
             getter(CookiesService.prototype, name, function() {
                 try {
                      CookiesService.prototype.isCookie(name);
                      return $cookies.get(name);
                  } catch (e) {
                      throw new Error('Invalid cookie'); // never thrown!
                  }
             });

             /*Setter code*/


             return new CookiesService();
         });
     }
]);
```

So basically, if I want to retrieve a cookie after setting it, I would simply call CookiesServices.

Howeber, if I try to call the getter to retrieve a cookie that doesn't exist, I expect to get an error in the console. Since I have the throw, but it seems that it is not working and I am not able to debug and see whether the code gets executed at this level or not.

Example: CookiesService.cookie3 <- gives me undefined, no error thrown.

Also assuming that I do as follows:

```
CookiesService.prototype.isCookie = function(name) {
return cookies.hasOwnProperty(name);
};

Object.keys(cookies).forEach(function(name) {
getter(CookiesService.prototype, name, function() {
 if (!CookiesService.prototype.isCookie(name)) {
    throw new Error("blabla");
}
  return $cookies.get(name);
});
```

it won't throw the blabla error if I try to call CookiesService.cookie2

Comment: You `return new CookiesService();` from the `forEach` callback (which doesn't make sense) instead of from the `service` callback. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't use a class/constructor function if you only instantiate a singleton. Especially not if it doesn't even have properties or state. Just use an object literal instead.

Comment: @Bergi could you explain more why "shouldn't"? I mean what would go wrong with this

Comment: It's overcomplicated, inefficient, and confusing the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it might be a good idea to rename your `function getter(){}` to `function createGetter(){}`. This will make things easier to understand especially with the last param on said function *also* named "getter".

Second, you stated:

> Howe[v]er, if I try to call the getter to retrieve a cookie that doesn't exist...

This simply will never happen: 
Remember your `foreach` loop is creating getters for **existing** cookies (the stuff defined under `var cookies`). There will never be a getter defined on your service object that doesn't also have a corresponding value under `cookies`; thus doing something like `CookiesService.cookie3` isn't calling a getter at all.

If you think about it, how *could* you expect to exercise code (e.g., `get: function(){...})` for a getter that's never been defined anyways?

So calling `CookiesService.cookie3` will never execute code that you setup for existing cookies and therefore will never break into your error throws.

What you are seeing with the 'undefined' error is JS literally telling you it's not a function, it's not a getter, it's not a property... it's not anything defined on the object `CookiesService`.

Comment: Ops, you are right. Didn't notice that cookie3 doesn't have a getter and hence the code won't be executed. I was really waiting that explanation. Thank you and sorry for the typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for undefined instead of waiting for an error. Yes in javascript you can access an undefined value. As long as you don't try to access a value within the undefined you won't get an error

```
Object.keys(cookies).forEach(function(name) {
getter(CookiesService.prototype, name, function() {
  CookiesService.prototype.isCookie(name);
  if ($cookies.get(name) !== undefined) return $cookies.get(name)
  else throw new Error('Invalid cookie');
});
```

Comment: That's not the purpose of what I was doing in my Code.

If you notice, you will see that I will have pre defined cookie names in my code.

I'm checking here if the cookie name I provided in the get function call is already exists in the cookies object. 

So if I do CookiesService.cookie1, this might give me a value or undefined without an issue. However, CookiesService.cookie3 would should throw me an error and not undefined. I don't want to call $cookies.get() with a cookie name that is not defined in my cookies object